# Firefox can't detect Flash player plugin when running in a docker container

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, docker, plugins, flash-player

I'd like to run ***Firefox 84.0*** (the last version support *flash player*) supporting **flash player** in a ***docker container***. But Firefox can't detect the flash player plugin which is in the path "~/.mozilla/plugins" named "libflashplayer.so"(Shockware Flash 25.0). I can't find it in "about:addons" or "about:plugins", only the plugin "OpenH264" is there.

Firstly, and the most importantly, I had tried to ***run Firefox with flash player on my real system*** (Debian 12 Linux 6.1.0-17-amd64) and a virtual machine in VirtualBox, and they both worked. But when Firefox is running in a container (docker version:25.01, image from ubuntu:22.04 amd64), it can't find the flash player plugin. The process of the creating the image and the container as follow:

```
#Dockerfile
From ubuntu:22.04
ENV MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX=1
WORKDIR /root
RUN apt update && apt install -y wget ......(some other libraries are needed) && \ 
 wget xxxx/firefox-84.0.tar.bz2 && tar jxvf firefox-84.0.tar.bz2 && rm *tar.bz2 && \  
 mkdir -p .mozilla/plugins
COPY libflashplayer.so .mozilla/plugins
ENTRYPOINT ./firefox/firefox

#image-bulid.sh
docker build -t firefox .

#container-run.sh
docker run --rm -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
  -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --device /dev/dri firefox
```

By the way, about the environment variable "MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX", without it I can't run the old version of Firefox, I found it from https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1020894

I searched around this problem, and tried some solutions such as:

- copy the libflashplayer.so to /usr/lib/firefox/plugins, /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins and other positions I find from many answers that "where is the position of Firefox plugins" and "why flashplayer doesn't work"
- use other version of Firefox like Firefox 83.0
- as Firefox that can detect the plugin running on my real system, I try to create a same user in the container, and copy all the Firefox files in my real machine like "~/friefox/", "~/.mozilla/" and "~/.cache/mozilla/ to the container with their original mode (use 'docker cp -a'). The user profile works but Firefox still hasn't flash player. I export data from "about:support", followings are the difference of a same Firefox between run in a real system and run in a container:

  ```
    test@test:~$diff support-real.json support-container.json
    29a30
    >       "web": 1,
    38,39c39,40
    <     "DISPLAY": ":0.0",
    <     "MOZ_ASSUME_USER_NS": "1",
    ---
    >     "DISPLAY": "unix:0.0",
    >     "MOZ_ASSUME_USER_NS": "0",
    41c42
    <     "MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_RESTART_ARG_0": 
    "/home/test/firefox/firefox",
    ---
    >     "MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_RESTART_ARG_0": "./firefox/firefox",
    75,77d75
    <     "plugin.flash.arch": "x86_64-gcc3",
    <     "plugin.flash.blockliststate": 0,
    <     "plugin.flash.desc": "Shockwave Flash 25.0 r0",
    80,81d77
    <     "plugin.flash.path": 
    "/home/test/.mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so",
    <     "plugin.flash.version": "25.0.0.127",
    225c171
    <     "hasUserNamespaces": true,
    ---
    >     "hasUserNamespaces": false,
  ```

  It's no use to add preferences like 'plugin.flash.xxx' manually, Firefox will overwrite them.
- I have tried to run other browsers fork of Firefox on Debian, Centos and different image of containers, only in container don't detect plugins.

I haven't not tried to put other plugin to the path "~/.mozilla/plugins" to make sure whether the key is "Firefox in container can't detect any plugins" or "Firefox in container just can't detect flash player", cause I can't find any other plugins to test.

So why the same Firefox progress with the same flash player plugin work difference between running in a whole system (real machine and virtual machine) and running in a docker container and how to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried to copy the Firefox profile from the environment where it works?

Comment: Also remember that Flash is long dead and a particular working environment (luck) may not work in another environment

Comment: @harrymc - Yes, I have. As I mentioned above the tried solutions, I copy all the files, and actually the profiles are in paths like 'xxx.default/' and 'xxx.default-release/'. To match the path in this files I add a same user in container, Firefox loads the profile and overwritten some  preferences, like 'plugin.flash.path', though I add it via "about:config" in Firefox, it dosen't work.

Comment: @John - I know that. I also try some browsers fork of Firefox and run in different systems, the same result that just in container can't work! So, I think it' just some difference between the environment of container and the environment of a whole system, and that make Firefox doesn't detect plugins. I am trying to read the documents of Mozilla Firefox to find out how Firefox automatically detects plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your docker situation, but I would highly recommend using a Flash emulator instead.

- https://gitlab.com/cleanflash/installer
- https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle

Also check this good source on emulation:
https://emulation.gametechwiki.com/index.php/Flash#Implementations

If you really need a browser with Flash support, consider installing Waterfox Classic, Pale Moon or K-Meleon. They are forks of Mozilla Firefox with built-in Flash Player support (source: Clean Flash website linked above).

Answer (score 0):

At last, I finally find out the solution, it's just a problem of **missing dependency packages**.

1. Make sure you don't lose the **dependency packages** of the plugins:

```
  ldd /path/to/libflashplayer.so | grep "not found"
```

2. And then install the lacked packages:

```
  apt install xxx
```

3. Don't forget to delete or modify **the plugin profile of Firefox**: `rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/xxx.defalut-release/pluginreg.dat` or change the path of plugins and `export MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/NEW_PATH/TO/PLUGIN`. (Firefox uses a file to register the plugins that had already been detected, it will **not check** the plugins that had been tagged as '**invalid**'.)

My conclusion:

- In my situation, it's clear that the one of difference between a program running in a docker container and running in a whole system is their environments. A container is **not an operating system with complete packages** as the OS we usually use. That's the reason why Firefox with flash in my host or a virtual machine can work while in container can't.
- In daily use, when a program failed to start, it usually prompts an error message like "xxx.so not found" or "xxx.dll is missing". But when Firefox failed to load Flash player, **there are no reminders**, neither Firefox nor Flash player.
- Most of times, a plugin or application is packaged with fully dependency packages. I had never thought about that flash plugin is just a shared object and needs other files. I searched some key words in the path of Firefox and found out the file named "**pluginreg.dat**' which masked libflashplayer.so as invalid. And then I scanned the source codes of Firefox, found that Firefox will detect some paths to register and load the plugins. By Debugging, I found out Firefox failed to load the dynamically linked library "libflashplayer.so", I means that the function "LoadLibrary()" returns error, that's exactly the problem.